# Django/Celery/Droplet: starting celery fails with supervisor, but works manually with same script (AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.)

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

I can call a worker with my `celery_init.sh`. It receives tasks and processes them in the way I would expect, as confirmed with flower. I **can't** get supervisor to start celery automatically with the same script.

`terminal$ ./celery_init.sh` **works perfectly**.

`terminal$ sudo supervisorctl restart celery` **fails like this**:

*Traceback*

```
[2017-07-18 21:07:28,475: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 203, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 115, in start
    self.on_start()
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 143, in on_start
    self.emit_banner()
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 158, in emit_banner
    ' \n', self.startup_info(artlines=not use_image))),
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py", line 221, in startup_info
    results=self.app.backend.as_uri(),
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 1182, in backend
    return self._get_backend()
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 900, in _get_backend
    self.loader)
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/backends.py", line 65, in by_url
    return by_name(backend, loader), url
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/backends.py", line 45, in by_name
    cls = symbol_by_name(backend, aliases)
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_celery_results/backends/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .database import DatabaseBackend
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_celery_results/backends/database.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..models import TaskResult
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_celery_results/models.py", line 17, in <module>
    class TaskResult(models.Model):
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 110, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/realestateleads/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

*Supervisor Config File*

```
; =========================
;  celery worker supervisor 
; =========================

[program:celery]

command=/home/realestateleads/bin/celery_init.sh

directory=/home/realestateleads/RealEstateLeads/DjangoRealEstateLeads
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/realestateleads/logs/celery/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/home/realestateleads/logs/celery/worker_err.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

stopwaitsecs = 600

killasgroup=true

priority=1000
```

*celery_init.sh*

```
export SECRET_KEY='MYSECRETKEYHERE'
/home/realestateleads/bin/celery --app=base.celeryapp:app worker --loglevel=INFO -n worker.%%h
```

celeryapp.py

```
import os

from celery import Celery, shared_task

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'base.settings')

app = Celery('DjangoRealEstateLeads')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my supervisor config file.

I had to change `user=nobody` to `user=realestateleads` (ie: my username). I'm not sure why; permissions are confusing! It works.